# Test onCall https cloud function locally

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have this call `export const notificationsCall = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { }`

When I deploy it and call it from my iOS app `functions.httpsCallable("getNotifications").call() { (result, error) in }` everything works fine and I do get proper response.

However when I run `firebase emulators:start --only functions` and navigate to the given url `http://localhost:5001/post-dach/us-central1/getNotifications`

All I get is this result. 
I'm using Postman and am doing a `Post` request with

`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`

Body

```
{
    "data": {
        "aString": "some string"
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "result": null
}
```

Also when I try to log something in the terminal, it does not appear and all I get is a big log from firebase.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

My function

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { Notification, Request } from '../models'
const db = admin.firestore();

export const notificationsCall = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const notificationsQuery = db.collection('notifications')

    const notifications: Notification[] = [];

    return notificationsQuery.get().then(snapshot => {
        const requestsRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference[] = [];
        const notIndexes: number[] = [];

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            notifications.push(doc.data() as Notification);
        });

        notifications.forEach((notification, index) => {
            if (notification.requestReference) {
                requestsRef.push(notification.requestReference);
                notIndexes.push(index);
            }
        });

        return db.getAll(...requestsRef);
    }).then((requests) => { // kthen requests
        const packagesRef: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference[] = [];

        requests.forEach((req, index) => {
            const requestt = req.data() as Request

            packagesRef.push((requestt).packageReference)
            notifications[index].request = requestt
        })

        return db.getAll(...packagesRef)
    }).then(packages => {
        packages.forEach((pkg, index) => {
            notifications[index].request.package = pkg;
        })

        return { notifications: notifications };
    }).catch(err => { err })

});
```

Comment: It sounds like your function just isn't returning what you expect.  We don't know what it's supposed to return instead (we can't see your data).  Please edit your question to be clear about what the function is supposed to return, given the specific data you're working with.  You should probably also do some logging in your function to verify it's doing everything correctly at every stage.

Comment: I have tried logging just {"a": "b"} and its the same. Also in the question I have written : `Also when I try to log something in the terminal, it does not appear and all I get is a big log from firebase.`

Comment: What is the "something" that you're trying to log?  Start with simple strings.